# Dynamically add checkbox to ASP.NET table row

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkboxlist

I am trying to add a checkboxlist and then add a new checkbox to every row in an ASP.NET table:

```
Dim cbList As New CheckBoxList
cbList.ID = "cb_list"

Dim c1 As New TableCell
Dim c2 As New TableCell        

Dim r As New TableRow

c1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(dr.GetString(1)))
c2.Controls.Add(cbList.Items.Add("new cb")) 'error: expression does return a value

r.Cells.Add(c1)
r.Cells.Add(c2)

modaltable.Rows.Add(r)
```

The c2.Controls line returns the following error:

"expression does return a value"

I can't seem to get round this problem. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to add single checkbox or list of checkbox ??

Comment: I want to create a checkbox for every row in the table, but make them part of the "cb_list" checkboxlist so that I can then iterate through it later on and see which ones are checked.

Comment: For that there is no need to add checkboxlist. just add single checkbox in each row and then iterate through each row and find checkbox control and get the status.

Comment: I thought it would be easier to create a list.
I have got this so far then:
    For Each control In modaltable.Controls
            
    Next

Comment: Yes like that... hope you now get some idea... ;)

Comment: Getting there, thanks for your help.